Trouble mocking Jest function within API route call
I have been stuck trying to get a relatively simple mock of a function contained within a call to an API endpoint getRedemptionCodeById(redeemId) that does not return the mocked value, only undefined.
index.test.js:
// 1. Mock setup - must be first and simplest form
jest.mock('../../crud/redemptionCodes', () => ({
 getRedemptionCodeById: jest.fn()
}));

// 2. Imports after mock
import request from 'supertest';
import { getRedemptionCodeById } from '../../crud/redemptionCodes';

// 3. Test setup
const server = process.env.API_URL || "http://localhost:8000";
const testId = '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000';

describe('Redemption API', () => {
 beforeEach(() => {
  // Clear mocks but don't reset modules
  jest.clearAllMocks();
 });

 it('should return 400 if redeem code is not found', async () => {
  // Set up mock implementation
  (getRedemptionCodeById as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(null);
  // Debug mock setup
  console.log('Mock before request:', {
   isMock: jest.isMockFunction(getRedemptionCodeById),
   implementation: (getRedemptionCodeById as jest.Mock).getMockImplementation()
  });

  const response = await request(server)
   .put('/redemption/redeem')
   .send({
    redeemId: testId,
    newOwnerIdentity: 'test-identity',
    newOwnerTokenHolder: 'test-holder',
    redeemType: 'retail'
   });

  // Debug mock after request
  console.log('Mock after request:', {
   calls: (getRedemptionCodeById as jest.Mock).mock.calls,
   results: (getRedemptionCodeById as jest.Mock).mock.results
  });

  expect(getRedemptionCodeById).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(getRedemptionCodeById).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testId);
  expect(response.status).toBe(400);
  expect(response.body.message).toBe('Redeem Code not found in records');
 });
});


index.ts (relevant part):
 try {
        const { redeemId, newOwnerIdentity, newOwnerTokenHolder, redeemType } = req.body;

        const redeemCode: any = await getRedemptionCodeById(redeemId);
        console.log("Called getRedemptionCodeById with:", redeemId);
        console.log("REDEEM CODE: ", redeemCode);

        if (!redeemCode) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                status: 404,
                message: 'Redeem Code not found in records',
                timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
            });
        }

Testing console:
    console.log
      Mock before request: { isMock: true, implementation: [Function (anonymous)] }

      at src/api/redemptionCodes/index.test.ts:26:11

    console.log
      Mock after request: { calls: [], results: [] }

      at src/api/redemptionCodes/index.test.ts:41:11

  ● Redemption API › should return 400 if redeem code is not found
                                                                                                                                                                         
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      44 |   });
      45 |
    > 46 |   expect(getRedemptionCodeById).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

API console:
Route handler called with body: {
  redeemId: '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000',
  newOwnerIdentity: 'test-identity',
  newOwnerTokenHolder: 'test-holder',
  redeemType: 'retail'
}
Called getRedemptionCodeById with: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000
REDEEM CODE:  undefined

I would expect:
REDEEM CODE: null

